# Redirect in htaccess to same page without a certain parameter

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

For example, redirect:

```
/somepage.php?parameter1=jon&parameter2=3&lang=en&parameter4=5
```

to be redirected to:

```
/somepage.php?parameter1=jon&parameter2=3&parameter4=5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you remove parameter lang independently of other parameters for page `somepage.php`

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  (.*)(?:^|&)lang=(?:[^&]*)((?:&|$).*)
RewriteCond %1%2 (^|&)([^&].*|$)
RewriteRule ^somepage.php$ somepage.php?%2
```

Taken from the [Official Apache mod_rewrite Documentation](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString#Remove_a_Single_Key.2FValue)

Comment: Hi @Bogdan won't you mind accepting this answer as solved if it helped you? Or do you have any more questions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^perm1=([^&]+)&perm2=([^&]+)&perm3=([^&]+)&lang=([^&]+)&perm5=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /index.php?perm1=%1&perm2=%2&perm3=%3&perm5=%5 [NC,L,R]
```

Another option :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index.php\?perm1=([^&]+)&perm2=([^&]+)&perm3=([^&]+)&lang=([^&]+)&perm5=([^&\s]+) [NC]

RewriteRule ^index.php$ /index.php?perm1=%1&perm2=%2&perm3=%3&perm5=%5 [NC,L,R]
```

Comment: something more generic? what if I have n parameters?
Thanks!